# How can you move by how fast the frame rate is in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have some code for movement in my unity 3d game like:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FPSMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float speed;
    [SerializeField] float sprintMultiplier = 1.5f;

    Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveBy = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        float actualSpeed = speed;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
            actualSpeed *= sprintMultiplier;
        }
        
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveBy.normalized * actualSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

But when the frame rate is lower you move faster then when the framerate is higher. I can't find a answer on how to fix it. I can attach a video if it is necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html), in `rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveBy.normalized * actualSpeed * Time.deltaTime);` which is the time between frames. Since lower fps causes more time between frames, it will increase your speed. This is used to make the player travel for same amount of time under different fps.

Comment: Yeah I get that but there is a big difference because when the fps is High it jitters a lot, how can I fix this? Here is the video: https://youtu.be/xdg3dUMnkEA

Comment: Try turning on the [`interpolation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyInterpolation.html) on the player rigidbody to true/Interpolate. If this does not do anything, try putting `rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveBy.normalized * actualSpeed * Time.deltaTime);` in a FixedUpdate() function.(However, keep your input stuff in Update[this would cause you to create private variables]). The update function runs each frame, while Fixed update runs 50 times per second(you can change this in settings). You will probably have to remove `Time.deltaTime`.